# javascript return statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a bug where my code won't exit my routine.  I'm using a return statement... but it doesn't seem to be working.
I have the following code inside a click event:

```
    $.getJSON(      

          url = 'myserver/controller/checkforduplicate',
          parameters,
          function(data)  {
                        if (data=='true') {
                            alert(data);
                            $('#verror').html("A duplicate entry exists");      
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            );  
        console.log($('#myform').serialize() );
```

When I input data the should be considered a duplicate and trigger this click event, the system doesn't exit but still gets to the console.log statement.

**EDIT 1**

I've reviewed the answers found at:  [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)
But from what I'm reading, haven't I already defined a callback function? 
I thought that's what I was doing with the "function(data) {}" code... 
In addition to stackoverflow, I've been using:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-getjson.htm

It seems that in the above example, they are referring to their function(jd) as the callback.  According to the above article, the syntax is:

> $.getJSON( url, [data], [callback] )

Perhaps I'm still missing something... 
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That's ASYNC my friend :D.

Comment: Yes, `getJSON` takes a callback, but that's not what people are talking about when they say "you need to use a callback". I assume your `getJSON` call is inside of a function, right? (Otherwise, why are you trying to `return false`?) You need your *outer* function -- the one that *uses* `$.getJSON` -- to take a callback. Think of your outer function (which you haven't supplied here) as the `foo` function in [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/710446). Search for "`filtered_response`" on that question and you'll see what you should be doing.

Comment: apsillers - got it.  Yes, getJSON is being called inside of a function.  i'll give your suggestion a try.  thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You cannot return from an asynchronous function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

You need to use a callback.

Comment: thanks for the article.  i understand the concept. but i don't understand the sample code for creating a callback function.  I've edited my post to include a sample callback

Comment: Neal, I was under the impression that my "function(data)" was the callback method.  No?

Comment: I see.  i think apsillers answered my question above... i'll give it a try anyways.